# What's the time complexity model of this program?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int p = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();
        input.close();
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i = i * 2) {
            p++;
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < p; j = j * 2) {
            // statement;
        }
    }
}
```

My professor asked us this question in the lecture, we give two answers: O(log n)and O(log (log n)), but are all denied by him, he left it for us as a thinking question, I'm wondering the right answer but can't come up with other answer. Please help me!

sorry n should be 1!!!!!

Comment: Are you sure the 'i' was initialed by zero in the first for segment?I think if i=0 and then i=i*2 means i=0 forever.

Comment: sorry guyz, n should be 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>EDIT: I answered this question without noticing `i` was initialized to `0`. This answer is correct only if `i`'s initial value as stated in the question is a typo.</strike>

The two loops are not nested, which means you have to add the complexity of the first to the complexity of the second.

Since the first loop takes `O(log(n))` and the second takes `O(log(log(n))`, the total running time is `O(log(n)) + O(log(log(n)) = O(log(n))`.

First loop:

i goes from 1 to n, and is multiplied by 2 on each iteration. It will reach `n` after log<sub>2</sub>n iterations, which means after the loop `p`'s value is log<sub>2</sub>n (or log<sub>2</sub>n - 1).

Second loop:

j goes from 1 to log<sub>2</sub>n, and is multiplied by 2 on each iteration. It will reach log<sub>2</sub>n after log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>n) iterations.

Answer (score 0):

This code contains two loops, the first has complexity `O(log(N))`, the second has complexity `O(log(log(N)))`.

Possibly, the professor expects the answer to be the sum of these two expressions:
`O(log(N) + log(log(N)))`, though the second term is much smaller and can be ignored, thus resulting in `O(log(N))`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your professor want to mention the input may take more time than the loop? i think nextint will read the blanks before the number